# What is an Airbrake Notifier in android?

Tags: android, exception, airbrake, exception-notifier

I have come accross code for AirBrakeNotifier in an app. However, Before that i should know what it does. All i have come to know is that it tracks error. I could not find a documentation on it. Can anyone please tell? Thanks

Comment: Doesn't AirBrake work with ROR and iOS, if this is what you are referring too? https://airbrake.io/pages/home.

Comment: It works for android too, but the question is,  why is it used when we have `logcat` to see exceptions generated in an application?

Comment: 1. The website itself does not mention compatibility with Android. 2. Logcat is useful when you are testing the app. Once your app is deployed, you no longer have access to users logcat except crash reports that the user may or may not submit. Services like AirBrake will gather those reports and email them across to your registered email address. NOTE: It is highly recommended that you comment out or delete any and all log statements in you app. You risk displaying information that may or may not be sesitive.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i wanted, a high level description

Comment: Then, I am glad to have helped. ;-)

Comment: y dont u go for Bugsnag?  https://bugsnag.com/

Comment: I was just reading a code which had Airbrake notifier. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to this library

https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-android

The original owner now works on https://bugsnag.com/ which may be another tool to track errors in your android application. If you have an API Key, we should be able to find the account as we may already have errors for your app.

Ben from Airbrake.